# Equidistribution of $\{p_n^2 \alpha \}$

Tags: number-theory, ergodic-theory, diophantine-approximation, equidistribution

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime and $\alpha$ an irrational number.  Vinogradov proved that the sequence $\{p_n \alpha \}$ is equidistributed.  Is it known whether the sequence $\{p_n^2 \alpha \}$ is equidistributed?

I decided to crosspost to [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319338/equidistribution-of-p-n2%CE%B1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any polynomial in the primes with a non-constant irrational coefficient is equidistributed.  See [the mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319338/equidistribution-of-p-n2%CE%B1).